# Is the IEnumerable.OrderBy().First() optimisation in .Net Core 3.1 documented anywhere?

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, .net-core

One of the .Net Core versions (I'm not sure which) introduced an optimisation such that if you write code like this:

```
int smallest = new[]{ 7, 2, 4, 6, 0, 1, 6, 9, 8 }.OrderBy(i => i).First();
```

then its complexity is `O(N)` rather than `O(N.Log(N))`.

Is this documented anywhere? I don't want to rely on this optimisation if it isn't "official".

---

Sample code that shows the difference between .Net Core and .Net Framework:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[] test = { 7, 2, 4, 6, 0, 1, 6, 9, 8 };

            var comparer = new Comparer();
            var _ = test.OrderBy(i => i, comparer).First();
        }
    }

    class Comparer : IComparer<int>
    {
        public int Compare(int x, int y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Comparing {x} with {y}");
            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Try it online with .Net Framework: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XItXYL

Try it online with .Net Core: https://dotnetfiddle.net/swlc0O

Output with .Net Framework 4.8:

```
Comparing 0 with 7
Comparing 0 with 8
Comparing 0 with 9
Comparing 0 with 6
Comparing 0 with 1
Comparing 0 with 0
Comparing 0 with 2
Comparing 0 with 6
Comparing 0 with 4
Comparing 0 with 2
Comparing 0 with 0
Comparing 7 with 2
Comparing 7 with 4
Comparing 7 with 6
Comparing 7 with 7
Comparing 7 with 8
Comparing 7 with 9
Comparing 7 with 6
Comparing 7 with 1
Comparing 7 with 7
Comparing 7 with 1
Comparing 9 with 7
Comparing 9 with 9
Comparing 9 with 8
Comparing 7 with 7
Comparing 7 with 8
Comparing 7 with 7
Comparing 6 with 2
Comparing 6 with 4
Comparing 6 with 6
Comparing 6 with 1
Comparing 6 with 6
Comparing 6 with 6
Comparing 6 with 1
Comparing 6 with 6
Comparing 6 with 6
Comparing 4 with 2
Comparing 4 with 4
Comparing 4 with 1
Comparing 2 with 2
Comparing 2 with 1
```

Output for .Net Core 3.1:

```
Comparing 2 with 7
Comparing 4 with 2
Comparing 6 with 2
Comparing 0 with 2
Comparing 1 with 0
Comparing 6 with 0
Comparing 9 with 0
Comparing 8 with 0
```

Comment: what  I digged https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14867 https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/2401

Comment: *"`OrderBy` followed by `Count()` also runs almost instantly… did Microsoft invent a O(1) sorting algorithm?"* - quote from [this blog](https://thomaslevesque.com/2017/03/29/linq-performance-improvements-in-net-core/) at 2017

Comment: And https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/19949/files/7143ae6453d6e3ff35274a7e2dd75eb9b269ac61#diff-1a0c924fd394ad4f534afe9a2a2e55515b6adb2e0ce5c14c45595db76442a561

Comment: Thanks both - that answers my question! @DragandDrop If you can turn that into something more than a link-only answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I was impressed on your clear writting for that question. I'm not confident in making it into an intelligible answer. Anyone can turn it into a answer.

Comment: The only gripe I have is that really this is the sort of thing that *should* be documented properly by Microsoft and not just in GitHub - some people want to know the performance characteristics of the fundamental Linq operations in order to make correct design decisions!

Comment: The `OrderBy()` + `Count()` optimization (actually `Select()` + `Count()`) is a perfect example of why this question is important. Read down near the end of the article and it was identified as a breaking change (side-effects from `Select()` where lost). There was a reference to a fix which isn't discussed, but likely rolled back the optimization. It's also an example of why this question is _not_ important. Performance metrics are best handled using profiling and as part of your unit tests. Write the code you need to write, test and profile to identify concerns, and optimize that first.

Comment: Implementation details are generally not documented.

Comment: @mm8 I would hope that fundamental sorting and searching operations have their complexity documented. For example, [the documentation for `List<T>.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netcore-3.1) states that it is an `O(N.Log(N))` operation. Without such guarantees, I'm forced to use, say, a `.MaxBy()` extension rather than using `.OrderBy().First()`. In fact, this is the entire raison d'être for my question!

Comment: Be aware that latest changes in `System.Linq`, like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/36051), may introduce some [bugs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39864)

Comment: Being "forced" to use an implementation with known complexity if this is important to you application, instead of whatever combination of operators Microsoft has decided to (un)optimize this week under particular circumstances, does not sound like a bad thing at all. Especially since the docs notoriously lag behind the implementation in this regard. Unlike methods like `List.Sort`, which operate on one collection only, the operations of `Enumerable` cannot realistically come with complete docs on complexity, since this also depends on the exact kind of collection they happen to operate on.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is exactly what I was complaining about. It should be possible to define important characteristics - [the C++ STL does so](https://alyssaq.github.io/stl-complexities/).

Comment: C#'s LINQ and the C++ STL are *very* different beasts. Of course it's *possible* to define LINQ operations in the same terms, but barring a major ideological shift I don't see it happening. Even with that a footnote would be needed along the lines of "applies only to LINQ to Objects", as obviously it would be far too constricting to demand that arbitrary query providers meet the specs (nor would that even necessarily have a practical use, as the actual running time would remain dependent on external factors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question "Is this optimisation documented" is: Yes (kind-of).

See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14867 for the discussion and links to the GitHub commits that implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't officially documented in the Microsoft documentation on those LINQ operators ([OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0) and [First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-5.0)).

This is intentional. Once a behavior is officially documented this way, any change to that behavior becomes a breaking change, which may limit the developers' ability to make *other* optimizations which may be even more beneficial. If you are going to *rely* on specific implementation details, you should probably write your own method for this purpose.

That said, it's relatively rare for the `O(n)` versus `O(n log(n))` complexity to make the difference between acceptable and unacceptable performance in an application. Consider carefully whether you're engaging in premature optimization.