# How to return sum of two highest value in List<int> in most efficient way? C#

Tags: c#, list, performance, latency, low-latency

I'm trying to pass a pre-written test with focus on performance. What is the most efficient way to return the sum of the two highest numbers in a List of int? I have tried the following and according to the test it wasn't fast enough when it comes to larger lists:

```
1.  list.Sort();
    list.Reverse();
    return list[0] + list[1];

2.  return list.OrderByDescending(num => num).FirstOrDefault() + list.OrderByDescending(num => num).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

3.  var secondHighest = list.Distinct()
                            .OrderByDescending(i => i)
                            .Skip(1)
                            .First();

    return list.Max() + secondHighest;
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the highest value appears twice? Is then highest and second highest that same value?

Comment: Related: [Extract the k maximum elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089373/extract-the-k-maximum-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: @Fildor There's no need to return the sum of distinct int's. If the two highest values are the same, return the sum of them anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Any straightforward sorting operation would be O(n*log(n)) (`OrderBy(Descending)`, `Sort`) at best (on random data) though current task is achievable in O(n) with a simple loop (assuming there are at least 2 items in the list of course, for the case when there are 2 or less elements just return `list.Sum()`):

```cs
var first = int.MinValue;
var second = int.MinValue;
foreach(var i in list)
{
    if(i > first)
    {
        second = first;
        first = i;
    }
    else if(i > second)
    {
        second = i;
    }
}

var result = first + second;
```

Also it worth noting that there can be implementation depended LINQ optimizations for some of cases like combination of `OrderBy(Descending)`with operators like `First(OrDefault)` or possibly `Take` (see [one](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/2401), [two](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14867), [three](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/orderby-firstordefault-complexity-increase)).

Comment: Note that this will return the wrong value if the list only contains one item.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar yes, already added comment

Comment: @MindSwipe personally I would just check length of the list and return `list.Sum()`

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm proposing this algorithm:

```
highest = 0
highestSet = false
secondHighest = 0
secondHighestSet = false
foreach item in list
    if item >= highest or !highestSet
        if highestSet
          secondHighest = highest
        highestSet = true
        highest = item
    else if item >= secondHighest or !secondHighestSet
        secondHighestSet = true
        secondHighest = item

return highest + secondHighest
```

Input set of [3, 2, 3, 2], it will return 6. This is O(n) time complexity.

For a set of [3], it will return 3.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ can be a very good solution for it.

```
long sum = 0;
if(list.Count > 1) 
  sum = list.OrderByDescending(z=>z).Take(2).Sum();
else
  sum = list.Sum();
```

Comment: The question was about performance/efficiency.  Do you think your solution using Linq especially the call to OrderByDescending makes it falling into that group?

Comment: @Ralf apparently the LINQ includes performance optimizations that make the `OrderByDescending`+`Take` a solution with O(n) complexity. At least this is what my benchmarks show on .NET 6.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Can you share how you benchmarked? Linq uses Quicksort here so it should be O(n*log(n)). And the way Quicksort works it does not tend to have highest/lowest value positioned fast. So i don't see how a optimization for take should work without sacrificing performance in most other cases. And, by the way, i can't see anything like that in the sourcecode of Net6.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665974/is-the-ienumerable-orderby-first-optimisation-in-net-core-3-1-documented-an

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The optimisation is only done for `.First()` - if you use `Take(2)` it will do a full sort. See [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0BTK7Q)

Comment: Anyway, this solution will be `O(N.Log(N))` in the general case, because of the `Take(2)`.

Comment: @Ralf I posted my findings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089373/extract-the-k-maximum-elements-of-a-list/72869657#72869657 "Extract the k maximum elements of a list").

Answer (score -1):

You can try this simple way:

```
list.Sort();
list.Reverse();
var secondHighest=list.Take(2).Sum();
 
return secondHighest;
```

or

```
 list=list.OrderByDescending(o=>o).ToList();
 var secondHighest=list.Take(2).Sum();
 
return secondHighest;
```

At first, it sorts your list, then reverses it , now you have descending sorted list , than it will take 2 highest elements and aggregate them .